# TextModulesData not showing on Generic Google Wallet passes

Tags: google-wallet

I'm working through the official documentation for Google Wallet Generic Passes https://developers.google.com/wallet/generic/web#c_2

I'm following the .NET implementation but have also tried nodeJS.  Basically, I can build a pass, and it shows header, logo, title, etc... but no text modules data!  This is copying their code *directly*, so my code/JSON looks exactly like the code/JSON in the tutorial. I did remove certain unnecessary fields like Hero Image because it was making the JWT > 1800 characters.

My question is: does anyone know how to make text module data actually work? I'm convinced this example is broken.  I've seen a similar thread for PHP. But I have not found a solution yet for .NET or otherwise.

Tried .NET and nodeJS implementations. This results in a pass without any text modules data.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVWmI.png)

Comment: I suspect they moved those fields to the "back" of the card because that's where they're appearing for me, but I'm not sure, hence why I'm here looking for the answer. ;)

Comment: I do think their example code is broken. I eventually did get textmodulesdata to show on the front of the card using a classtemplateoverride, but the example doesn't mention anything about that.